# Error when populating ngFor Table from Webserver

Tags: angular, typescript, fetch, ngfor

I try to fetch data from a web server and populate a table with `ngFor`.

This is my table where I use `ngFor`:

```
<div class="applic-liste">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let application of applications">
        <td>{{application.id}}</td>
        <td>{{application.name}}</td>
        <td>{{application.version}}</td>
        <td>{{application.fromTo}}</td>
        <td>{{application.description}}</td>
        <td>{{application.geography}}</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
  </table> 
  </div>
```

I have this class where I fetch the data:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { DbService } from '../../db.service.service';
import {Application} from '../application.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-applic-list',
  templateUrl: './applic-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./applic-list.component.css'],
  providers: [DbService],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ApplicListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _dbService:DbService) { }
  applications:any;  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(){
    this._dbService
       .getData()
       .subscribe(applications => {
         this.applications = applications;
     } )
 }

}
```

And this is my `service` where I connect to the web server:

```
@Injectable()
export class DbService {
  applications=[];
  private _serverUrl: string = "http://localhost/api/";
  constructor(private _http:Http) { }

 getData(){
    return this._http.get(this._serverUrl+'select.php').
    map((response:Response) => response.json);
  }
}
```

I also defined my applications array in this `class`:

```
export class Application implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  name: string;
  version: string;
  fromTo: string;
  description: string;
  geography: string;
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And these are the **error** I am getting:

[image]

Can someone help me with this. I am new to Angular.. and I don't know where the problem is

I appreciate your answers!

**EDIT:**
And this is my json-response:
`[{"id":"1","name":"TestName","version":"1.2","fromTo":"Test","description":"Beschreibung","geography":"Geography"}]`

Comment: how does your response look like? applications

Comment: do you mean my json data i am getting from the web server? see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error suggest that applications is Observable not arry

```
*ngFor="let application of applications | async"
```

Comment: I tried this before but I am getting additional errors:
`Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'function ()` ...

Comment: change this line from    map((response:Response) => response.json); to    map((response:Response) => response.json());